# Toggling a boolean with link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

I've read through the relevant Stack questions but still seem to be hitting a routing error with the following code:

## Routes.rb

```
resources :memberships do
  put :toggleon
  put :toggleoff
end
```

## Memberships_controller.rb

```
 def toggleon
    @membership = Membership.find(params[:id])
    @membership.update_attributes(:active => true)
    if user.id == membership_id 
       redirect_to root_path
    else
       redirect_to group
    end
 end

 def toggleoff
    @membership = Membership.find(params[:id])
    @membership.update_attributes(:active => false)
          if user.id == membership_id 
       redirect_to root_path
    else
       redirect_to group
    end
 end
```

## Show.html.erb

```
  <% if this_membership.active %>
    <%= link_to 'Pause', this_membership, controller: :memberships, method: :toggleoff, style: 'color:#ccc' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to 'Start', this_membership, controller: :memberships, method: :toggleon, style: 'color:green' %>
  <% end %>
```

## Error text

```
Started POST "/memberships/13" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-09-27 23:35:35 +0100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/memberships/13"):
```

I can destroy memberships just fine but toggling the membership activity is proving tricky.

Thanks in advance!

## Second attempt

```
                  <%= link_to("Pause", membership_toggle(@membership), :method => :put, :title => "This toggles it off") %>
                  <% else %>
                  <%= link_to("Toggle On", membership_toggle(@membership), :method => :put, :title => "This toggles it on") %>
```

and

```
def toggle
   @membership = Membership.find(params[:id])
   @membership.toggle!(active)
end
```

and

```
resources :memberships do
   member do
      put :toggle
   end
end
```

now gives me this error...

```
undefined method `membership_toggle' for #<#<Class:0x00000102e69bc0>:0x00000102e66ec0>
```

Comment: This may or may not help with the routing, but what if you had a single method, `toggle`, and passed `:active => !@membership.active` to `update_attributes`?

Comment: Where you have `membership_toggle(@membership)`, this should be: `membership_toggle_url(@membership)`. You're missing the `_url` part at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Links using your routes are going to be:

```
link_to("Toggle On", membership_toggleon_url(membership), :method => :put, :title => "This toggles it on")
link_to("Toggle Off", membership_toggleoff_url(membership), :method => :put, :title => "This toggles it off")
```

You need to supply `:method => :put` to the link_to method given that's what you have the route as in your routes file.

Something like this can be achieved with a single action:

```
resources :memberships do
  member do
    put :toggle
  end
end
```

Then you can make use of a single boolean field in your controller by using the Rails [toggle](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/toggle) method.

This will let you do something like:

```
@membership.toggle(:on)
```

Comment: Please show an example of how to use these routes within the context of a `link_to`. I think it will make your answer better! :)

Comment: Now I'm getting: No route matches {:action=>"toggleoff", :controller=>"memberships"}

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the route as being `:on => :member`.

Also, there's an atomic `toggle!` method that does what its name implies.