# ROR 4 On/Off variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, persistent

I need set a variable that its persistent but being able to change the value to true or false from a view, like a switch (on/off) button, i believe that use a database table to store one value is not the right way, any ideas?

Im using ROR 4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggling a boolean with link\_to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576497/toggling-a-boolean-with-link-to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a cache store...
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html